# I want to use the factory method in enum, but for some reason it is not available in my environment

Tags: flutter, dart, enums, factory

We have defined the following enum.

```
enum City {
  us,
  korea,
  canada,
  other;

  factory City.fromName(String name) => switch (name) {
        'us' => City.us,
        'korea' => City.korea,
        'canada' => City.canada,
        _ => City.other,
      };
}
```

And I would like to use it this way, but it is not available in my environment.

```dart
City.fromName(city);
```

If you write it like this, you can use it.

```dart
City.korea.fromName(city);
```

I heard that others can use `City.fromName(city);` but not me.
How can I use the factory method in enum?

Flutter: 3.16.5
Dart: 3.2.3

Comment: Can you provide a link where it shows that others can use `City.fromName(city)`?

Comment: This way.
https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/18p2p7e/comment/keld5i9/?context=3

Comment: I tried your code in DartPad, it works just fine https://dartpad.dev/?id=cf402bbb1e0a3b1e5a305a57648208e7

Comment: Yes, I know. I know. That's why I'm asking the question here, because I'm having trouble finding the cause.

Comment: But you didn't mention what problem you get there. It's not clear what you meant by "not available in my environment"

Comment: I am also uncertain.

Comment: Then clarify. It is not clear what you meant by "not available in my environment". What's "environment"? What's not available? What's the error that preventing you from doing that? They're not mentioned in the question.